# Как делить списки друг на друга?

Tags: python, list, список, арифметика

Есть список n[1,2,3,4] и список c[1,3,4,5]. Как поделить последовательно 1/1 2/3 3/4 4/5?

Answer (score 7):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array(n)
c = np.array(c)
res = n / c
```

---

Vanilla Python:

```
res = [a/b for a,b in zip(n, c)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [21]: res
Out[21]: array([1.        , 0.66666667, 0.75      , 0.8       ])
```

---

PS для списков *различной длины*:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

n = [1,2,3,4]
c = [3,2,1]
res = [a/b for a,b in zip_longest(n, c, fillvalue=1)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [28]: res
Out[28]: [0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант так:

```
for index in range(min(len(n), len(c))):
    print(n[index]/c[index])
```

Comment: Ну это уж совсем не pythonic way, лучше уж из zip (n,c) элементы перебирать. Индекс вообще не нужен.